# ViteJS - How to add multiple scripts to Classic Web Worker assets/ dir with vite build cli command

Tags: reactjs, web-worker, vite

Using vite `v2.9.14`

I have a classic web worker that uses importScripts('filename.js')

When using vite it works fine when building locally, however when I run vite build and everything is separated into chunks, the assets folder in the webworker does not contain the necessary scripts that I am importing.

File structure

```
-- components
  -- Player
  -- libffmpeg.wasm
  -- libffmpeg.js
  -- decoder.js
  -- downloader.js
  -- websocket.js
```

Current vite config

```
envDir: root,
root: path.resolve(root, './app/src'),
plugins: [
    react({
        jsxRuntime: 'automatic',
    }),
],
optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
        keepNames: true,
    },
},
build: {
    target: 'esnext',
    outDir: path.resolve(root, './app/dist'),
    emptyOutDir: true,
}
```

How I am creating web worker

```
new Worker(
        new URL('./downloader.js', import.meta.url),
    );
```

Where webworker fails

```
importScripts('libffmpeg.js')
```

What worker looks like when I `vite mode --development`. [image: successful scripts]
What worker looks like when I `vite build, then, vite preview` [image: how to add scripts to assets foler]

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm facing the same problem